# Phrase matching from paragraph using Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a doc/list of names of countries.

**id:countries
name:[Belize, Benin, Bhutan, Bolivia, Bosnia, Bosnia Herzegovina, Botswana, Brazil, Brunei]**

If my query is "I live in Bosnia Herzegovina", or more generally " * Bosnia Herzegovina *", Then I would like to see **countries** as query result.

I could only manage single word countries. Could anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**:

Here is my schema configuration for the field.

`<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>`

And I am searching like this: `http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=i love Bosnia Herzegovina&wt=json`

Comment: Share your existing searcher code.

Comment: Added that by editing in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Actually the problem was in the search query. We have to embed the query with a pair of first bracket. This will solve the problem.

Before: `http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=i love Bosnia Herzegovina&wt=json`

Solved: `http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=(i love Bosnia Herzegovina)&wt=json`